# How To Parse Date and Time from Tweets Listed in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: parsing, google-sheets, tweets

I have over 5,000 tweets in a spreadsheet. I copied them from another site and each one looks like this:

```
Josh Mitchell @mitchellmadnessTue Dec 16 22:24:27 +0000 (GMT) via Twitter Web Client0
Are you ready to party for the holidays and network your mistletoe off? #wickidpissa #elevate #publicityhttp://t.co/IoovyowZYO
```

That whole thing is in one cell, A2. The first line in that cell has the date and time. The second line in that same cell is the tweet, which we can ignore.

I want to be able to parse out the date and time from each cell in column A and put them into columns B and C, respectively. In the first line of each cell, the twitter handle and week day have no space between them. So in the example above, the day would be Tuesday and the time would be 22:24:27. Throughout the list of tweets, the days are represented as "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", etc.

Is there a formula or script I can run to easily capture this information across all of tweets in each cell?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, say in B2 [not per spec, for the second formula!]:

```
=mid(A2,find("(GMT)",A2)-22,15)
```

is deemed "fit for purpose".

To convert that to a date/time index (ignoring time zone issues etc and assuming the year is `2014`):

```
 =value(mid(B2,5,2)&"-"&left(B2,3)&"-2014")+right(B2,8)
```

With a date/time index the results could be copied into a different column and formatted so one shows date and the other time.